# MySQL Entity Framework 4.0 Stored Procedure Field Mapping

Tags: .net, mysql, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4, mysql-connector

Has anyone here used MySQL with the entity framework 4.0 and stored procedures?   When I add a SP, it does not show any of my fields that I need to input.  I also see no way to manually add them.  When I click Function Import Mapping, it simply says "Select an Entity or Association on the Entity Designer Model Browser to edit it's mapping".

Any help is appreciated.  I am using the .NET Connector 6.3.6

Comment: You'll find that it will be much simpler to manually call the stored proc using ExecuteStoreQuery and manually supplying the MySQL parameters that the query needs. I've tried to force the mappings into the edmx file before and it doesn't play nicely.

Comment: Yep that is what I have been doing for the time being. I would assume this will eventually be updated, but that works for now. Thank you

Comment: Probably wouldn't hurt to get a couple extra bug reports into the MySQL connectors bug tracker wouldn't it?

Comment: Any news since you since you asked this question?

Comment: I just made my model manually and ran the SQL myself to execute the SP =/.  Not what i was looking for but it works

Answer (score 10, accepted):

due to the bug #55778 (Stored procedure parameters are omitted during update of the entity data model) it is not possible to automatically import MySQL Stored Procedures into a entity data model.

As a workaround you could manually manipulate the created .edmx file (.ssdl, .csdl):

Import the MySQL Stored Procedure as discribed above

Search for the Stored Procedure name within the model (.edmx file or .ssdl, .csdl files)

Within the Storage Model (SSDL) replace:

```
  <Function Name="GetStudentGrades" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false"
            NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false"
            ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo">
  </Function>
```

with:

```
  <Function Name="GetStudentGrades" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false"
           NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false"
            ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo">
    <Parameter Name="StudentID" Type="int" Mode="In" />
  </Function>
```

Within the Conceptual Model (CSDL) replace:

```
  <FunctionImport Name="GetStudentGrades" EntitySet="StudentGrades" ReturnType=...>
  </FunctionImport>
```

with:

```
  <FunctionImport Name="GetStudentGrades" EntitySet="StudentGrades" ReturnType=...>
    <Parameter Name="StudentID" Mode="In" Type="Int32" />
  </FunctionImport>
```

Hope that helps!
Cheers

Comment: Hi, just want to ask is this fixed now? Could we automatically import mysql stored procedures into the entity data model now?

Comment: it doesnt appear to be fixed yet.   i'm encountering the same crap

Comment: After years they fix importing stored procedure but so long as your are returning a table or scalar data.  No complex types.  The bug was reported I guess six years ago or more, they keep updating the connector frequently but not sure what they change in there.  Since Oracle bought MySql I guess things have gone south.  Hopeless.