# How can I call a MYSQL SP from EF4

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I tried to add the SP the edmx file, but the input parameters are not shown. I tried to use the code below, but it errors out.

```
IEnumerable<Finance> userFinance =
((IObjectContextAdapter)this)
.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<Finance>("GetFinanceContent @userId", parameter);
```

I also tried:

```
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter
    {
        DbType= DbType.Int32,
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
        Value= 100,
        ParameterName ="userId"
    };
var results= db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand ("GetFinanceContent @userId", parameter);
```

This gives some parameters error.
Only MySqlParameter objects may be stored

Comment: have you done function import step for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woking with stored procedure in EF4 is so much easy. Here is no need to add Sp in edmx file you can get directly access to it just you have to use function mapping  just follow these rules ...

1. Update your model and add stored procedure in it.
2. now in model browser view go to Stored procedure folder you will see your added SP in it.
3. Now select SP and select the option "Create Function Import" by doing Right Click.
4. Now Function import Window would be open in it in the Return Type Section select the return type according to the data your SP returning..

   --> If your SP is returning exact match of an entity select that entity .If a scalar value then select its return type if not then you need to create an entity that exact match your SP result.
5. After that you can get access to SP like  this.

   ```
   using(EFEntity ef = new EFEntity ())
    {
       var results = from result in ef.YourSpName(Param1, param2,..)
                 select result
    }
   ```

Hope this will help you ..

Updated answer: 
As you are  saying you are not getting parameters it means that here is no parameter defined in your SSDL so you have to do this mannualy.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287460/mysql-entity-framework-4-0-stored-procedure-field-mapping) is the solution of your problem.

Good Luck

Comment: i had tried this approach, and since i am using MYSQL Db it seems the parameters are not shown when it pulls the SP to the model

Comment: @Natasha : after following these steps check your CSDL is it has defined your SP params there if not than you have to manually add it.

Comment: the link you gave is pointing the same problem that i told you.You have to manually add the params in CSDL because it is not getting it.And not just in that every alteration you made in edmx manually would be cleared when model will update and it is a common behavior.

Comment: the bug also says that 6.3.7 has fixed version but appartently that is not the case, becsaue i just installed that and still have same issue

Comment: @Natasha:The problem would remain and for now the solution is to  manually add params.  search out your sp in emdx file in both sections CSDL and SSDL and manually add your param there.If you read the link and follow it your problem should be solve

Comment: Does anyone knows how to do this in Code First (without edmx)?