# VS 2010 - Entity Framework with MySql Stored Procedure doesnt seem to work

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I want to work with Entity Framework (edmx file) and MySql database. For tables and views, VS 2010 works fine, that said, it can generate Model classes, csdl, ssdl etc files well. But, for stored procedures it doesn't work. Here is what happens..

1. Right clicked on an SP from Model Browser, select [Add Function Import]. This opened a dialog box
2. Filled appropriate values like, Function Import Name, Stored Procedure Name
3. Click on [Get Column Information]. This results into some Grid filled up at the bottom of this button. In the grid, there is a column named [EDM Type]. This column shows [Not supported] due to some unknown reason :(
4. Now, clicked on [Create New Complex Type]. This goes OK, without Error
5. Now, clicked on OK button

After doing all above steps, there is no Complex Type created in the code however, which is the problem.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Forgot to mention.. I am using, mysql-connector-net-6.4.4 for connection to mysql purpose.

Comment: hi, i am facing same issue did you get any solution to this problem please share.. thanks in advance.

Comment: /me is having the same issue, too  :(
when I click 'Get Column Information' the dialog box seems to crash out

Answer (score 0):

I 'solved' this by lettting Entity Framework create the paramerterless definition and associations and then manually added the parameters to the xml & generated cs file.

```
      public virtual ObjectResult<Nullable<int>> <stored_procedure>(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
    {
        ObjectParameter[] parameters = { new ObjectParameter("parametertName1",  date1)
                                              , new ObjectParameter("parametertName1",  date2)
                                              };

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Nullable<int>>("stored_procedure", parameters);
    }
```

also, [MySQL Entity Framework 4.0 Stored Procedure Field Mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287460/mysql-entity-framework-4-0-stored-procedure-field-mapping) explains more